# How to write a domain entity object to multiple database tables using Spring Data Jpa？

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, domain-driven-design, jhipster, model-driven-development

I have a domain model that corresponds to multiple tables when I use a relational database to design a data store. Now when I create this domain entity, I want to use Spring Data Jpa to write to multiple data tables at once. How to do it?

1.Domain Model:

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "startTime": "2018-07-09T08:59:08.853Z",
    "endTime": "2018-07-09T08:59:08.853Z",
    "group": 2,
    "entries": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "target": 90,
            "isFinished": false,
            "name": "俯卧撑",
            "groups": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "第一组",
                    "number": 30
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "第一组",
                    "number": 30
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

2.Data tables：

```
tb_execise_plan(id, start_time, end_time, group)
tb_execise_entry(id,name,target, is_finished, execise_plan_id, project_id)
tb_execise_entry_group(id,name,number,execise_entry_id)
```

3.Table relationship:

```
tb_execise_plan  1:m tb_execise_entry
tb_execise_entry 1:m tb_execise_entry_group
```

Comment: Your question as it stands is too broad. Add the code you have so far.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you look at Olivier Gierke/Drotbohm presentations and code samples about DDD and Spring data. It's a different approach than JHipster's entity generator which is about one JPA repository per entity.

But starting from JHipster generated repositories, you could aggregate your entities within a `@Service` annotated class using `@Transactional` annotated methods.

You can find an example of this approach in your JHipster generated project with `UserService` class which aggregates a `User` and its `Authorities`.